# Using neo4j import tool with integer IDs

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm new to Neo4j, and I'm trying to use its [import tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html) to import a bunch of legacy data into a new database.  The main ID for this data will be integers.  However, it seems that the :ID property of a node defaults to a string type?  I know I can use :int on other properties to make them integer type, but it doesn't seem possible to combine that with :ID.

For example, here's node type 1:

```
node1_int_id:ID(node1)|other_prop|another_prop
12345                 |foo       |bar
```

node type 2:

```
node2_int_id:ID(node2)|other_prop|another_prop
67890                 |foo       |bar
```

and the relationships

```
:START_ID(node1)      |:END_ID(node2)
12345                 |67890
```

This seems to work, but the result is a relationship based on two string-type fields.  So I guess I have two questions:

1)Am I doing this right?  Is there some way to make the ID fields integers that I'm not seeing?

2)If I have to do it this way, is it a problem that they are strings?  This will eventually result in a fairly large database of ~100 million nodes and relationships, so it seems like a bad idea to be looking for relationships based on a string comparison.

Comment: Neo4j's native IDs are numeric. Are you sure you are using native IDs, or are you using your own IDs? What neo4j driver are you using? Also, you should be aware that relying on native IDs is not a good idea. As [the warning here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#_get_node_or_relationship_by_id) states: "Neo4j reuses its internal ids when nodes and relationships are deleted. This means that applications using, and relying on internal Neo4j ids, are brittle or at risk of making mistakes. Rather use application generated ids."

Comment: These are my own IDs.  They come from index numbers in our existing relational database.

Comment: What language and neo4j driver are you using? This does not seem to be an issue with neo4j itself, since it can store integer properties.

Comment: I know that it can store integer properties.  When did "other_prop:int" it correctly stored that property as an integer.  But I wasn't able to combine that with designating a property as the ID.  doing "my_id:ID:int" and " "my_id:int:ID" doesn't work.  This is version 2.3.2, with a python back end.

Comment: Please show your actual Cypher queries.

Comment: I'm not doing creating these with Cypher queries, I'm using Neo4j's import tool: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html.  So the command would be like:  neo4j-import --into path_to_target_directory --nodes nodes1.csv --nodes nodes2.csv --relationships:MATCH node1_to_node2.csv

Comment: The fact that this was about the import tool is vital information that should have been in the Question. I have added that info.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm running into the exact same issue. I've tried both id:STRING:ID and id:ID:STRING but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Command line usage](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool-usage.html) page of the neo4j import tool documents this command line option:

> **--id-type <id-type>**
>
> One out of [STRING, INTEGER, ACTUAL] and specifies how ids in node/relationship input files are treated.
>
> STRING: arbitrary strings for identifying nodes. INTEGER: arbitrary integer values for identifying nodes. ACTUAL: (advanced) actual node ids.
>
> The default option is STRING.

So, you should specify `--id-type INTEGER` on the command line when running the import tool.

Comment: This works fine if all of your nodes have the same type of ID, but how would one do this if some nodes have integer IDs and some have String IDs?